# How do I make a SOAP(ASMX) call with MS Office Access 2007?

Tags: c#, web-services, ms-access, soap, asmx

I have a set of .ASMX API calls exposed and have a client that would like to call them using MS Office Access 2007. I have never used Access before and need to know how to connect to my services. What is the best way to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article on MSDN describes how to create a managed addin for Access 2007 that performs web service calls:

[Creating Managed Add-ins for Access 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902693(loband).aspx)